# Error after AppDelegate-Object in XIB? - OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, xib, appdelegate

I use the following to lines of code to make the MenuBar show up. There is just the MenuBar in the xib file MainMenu.xib. These lines are on top of the init method in my ViewController.

```
NSNib *nib = [[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"MainMenu" bundle:nil];
[nib instantiateWithOwner:self topLevelObjects:&array];
```

That works pretty good. But if I add an `NSObject` to this `xib` file and change its class in the Identity Inspector to `AppDelegate` I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Does anybody know why this error appears and how it could be solved?

Thank you in advice.

Comment: What do you mean by `change its class to AppDelegate` ?

Comment: I mean that i change it's class in the Identity Inspector. i'll edit it to make it clear for everybody. ty